# How do I continuously update these coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to move the rectangle horizontally,however,it enters the updateStageObjects() function several times but does not update the value of myRectangle.x.How do I fix this?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var interval = 10;
            var x=0;
            var y=0;
            var myRectangle;
            var context ;
            var canvas;
        function Rectangle(x, y, width, height, borderWidth) {
                this.x=x;
                this.y=y;
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
                this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
            }
        function DrawRects(){   
                myRectangle = new Rectangle (250,70,100,50, 5);      context.rect(myRectangle.x,myRectangle.y,myRectangle.width,myRectangle.height);        
                context.fillStyle="#8ED6FF";
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth=myRectangle.borderWidth;
                context.strokeStyle="black"; 
                context.stroke();
            }

            function updateStageObjects() {
                var amplitude = 150;
                var centerX = 240;  
                myRectangle.x += 100;
    alert(myRectangle.x+"   "+myRectangle.y);                   
            }    
            function clearCanvas() {                
                context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height); 
            }

            function DrawRect(){

                setTimeout(CheckCanvas,10);
                clearCanvas();
                updateStageObjects();
                DrawRects();
            }   
        function CheckCanvas(){
                return !!(document.createElement('canvas').getContext);

            }   

        function CheckSound(){
            return !!(document.createElement('sound').canPlayType)
            }

        function CheckVideo(){
            return !!(document.createElement('video').canPlayType)
            }

        function Checkstorage(){    
            return !!(window.localStorage)
            }


        function CheckVideo(){
            return !!(document.createElement('video').canPlayType)  
            }


        function DrawCanvas(){
            if (CheckCanvas()){
                canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
                DrawRects();
                setInterval(DrawRect, 10);      
            }
    }
</script>
```

html

```
   <canvas id="Canvas" width="800px" height="800px" onclick="DrawCanvas()"> Nor   supported</canvas>
```

Comment: Why so many empty lines in your code? And also the unnecessary indentation?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zCEyH/1/ @Vimal - Please use [console.log](http://getfirebug.com/logging) and not alerts in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `updateStageObjects()`, it is followed immediately by a call to `DrawRects()`, which creates a new rectangle at exactly `(250,70,100,50, 5)`. So you'll never notice it increment by 100.

You'll need to pass some numbers back and forth between these functions if you want one of them to remember the changes made in another.

Answer (score 2):

As Chris has pointed out your DrawRects() always draws the same co-ords, try adding a couple more variables like

```
var dx = 250;
var dy = 70;
```

Then change your `new Rectangle` to

```
myRectangle = new Rectangle (dx,dy,100,50, 5);
```

Next change your `myRectangle.x += 100` line to

```
dx += 100;
```

Hope this helps.